# Which traits are lost in the limit, and which are retained?

Tags: induction, cauchy-sequences

Let $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ be a Cauchy-series, and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = q\in \mathbb{R}$. 
Given a formula $A[x]$ where $x$ is a variable, let $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: A[q_n]$ be true.

Question: When does $A[q]$ hold?

I'm specially interested in this particular strategy: Let $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:B[x]$ be to prove.
If it's true, $\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}:B[x]$ follows.    Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, we can inductively prove this statement. Now we can define for every real number a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as above, and if we show $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: A[q_n] \implies A[q]$, we'd have our proof.

Is there some manageable criteria for when this strategy works?

---

Just as example: 
One such criteria is that if $A[a]$ holds and if there's a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ for which $\forall x\in U: A[x]$ holds. I.e.: 
If $\varphi$ is a formula and $U$ is a neighborhood, the following equivalence holds: 
 $\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}:(\varphi(x) \land   \exists U: \forall y\in U: \varphi(y))
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 
 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: \varphi(x)$

I also found another one:

Let $A[x_1,..,x_n]$ be a formula that's true for all $x_1,...x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$. If all functions and relations (excluding $=$ ) are continuous, then $A$ holds for all $x_1,..,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$.  The only drawback is that the continuousity has to be shown in $\mathbb{R}$ or has to be an axiom of the function/relation.

Comment: I don't think such a criteria exists. For example, let $A[x]$ be $1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise. Then you can make a sequence $q_n\to q$ with $q_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ which has $A[q_n]\equiv 1$ but $A[q]=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion is that $\{x:A[x]\text{ holds}\}$ must be a closed set. This can be stated directly as

> If every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point $y$ for which $A[y]$, then $A[x]$.

Another option: let $\overline A[x]$ mean that $A[x]$ does *not* hold.

> If $\overline A[x]$, then there is a neighborhood of $x$ so that $\overline A[y]$ for all $y$ in the neighborhood.

Comment: So let's say I've got two functions $f,g:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ with $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and let $f$ (or $g$) be continuous. How do I show $f = g$ for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Sudix Maybe ask that as a separate question?

Comment: If it was a difficult question, probably. But it should be a simple, straightforward application of your answer. The whole concept just seems foreign to me yet, so I wanted to check on my intuition